# Prestashop 1.6 Top Horizontal Menu internationalisation

Tags: menu, prestashop, multilingual

Is it actually possible to have different external links on each instance of Top Horizontal Menu depending on the current language selected?

So, for example, when the user is viewing the site in english the external link label will say "Home" and link to `xxxxxx.com/en.html` and when they are viewing the site in spanish the label will say "Inicio" and take them to `xxxxxx.com/es.html`?

The idea being that prestashop is installed on a subdomain of a larger multilingual site which has other non shop content and once the users are in the shop but might choose to navigate back to the non shop site.

This is easily done in *Joomla* or *Wordpress*, but I cannot find a way to do it in *prestashop*. Regardless of which language I encode into the Top Horizontal Menu only one label (and it`s link) shows up on all the different languages.

There doesn't seem to be a way to have various links and associate them.  Maybe I'm missing something here. Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question as it is already available in Blocktopmenu configuration.

When you create a new link you can enter a name and a url per language, and in database it's saved independently:

[image]
[image]

```
|----------------------------------------------------|
| TABLE ps_linksmenutop_lang                         |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|id_linksmenutop|id_lang|id_shop|label    |link      |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| 2             | 1     | 1     | tutu    | tutu.en  |
| 2             | 2     | 1     | test    | test.fr  |
|----------------------------------------------------|
```

So when you visit the site in French language you will get a link to `test.fr` and when you visit the site in English you will get a link to `tutu.en`.

If it doesn't work for you, please add more informations to your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I must still be missing something as I did exactly as you suggest. http://imgur.com/OJsVOSY 
http://imgur.com/TKyLoZX . Where its appears to go wrong is when I create the external link in spanish (in this example).   http://imgur.com/DUd6jsY . The new link is has an ID and that`s it (the other fields appear empty) .

Comment: When I try and add the invisible link the Menu Top Link filed look like this : http://imgur.com/3mKvtJI  I can highlight and add it but it`s invisible and subsequently when I view the site it has the english "Home" button on both the english and spanish version of the site.  http://imgur.com/h9K4Pbz  and  http://imgur.com/wCsyz0T

Comment: I understand what you did wrong. You created two different links instead of one. First delete the second link, you only need one. Then edit the first link and select the "Spanish" value next to its fields in the select box. Here type your Spanish name and link. If you select "English" in the select box again you will still see your english version. Save and that's it :)